# Is Positive Semidefinite matrix Same as Positive Number in Convex Optimisation?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the optimisation problem expressed in a crude form

$\max_{\mathbf{Q}}\sum w_ir_i$

where $w_i$ are constants, $r_i$ are concave functions of positive semidefinite matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ satisfying $\text{trace}[\mathbf{QA}]\leq P$ for some other positive semidefinite $\mathbf{A}$.

Given the objective function and the feasible region, the problem is obviously a convex problem. I studied about the concept of Lagrange and KKT multiplier applied to constraints expressed in terms of real valued functions. But for the positive definite constraint on $\mathbf{Q}$, is it possible to attach a KKT multiplier with it, as if $\mathbf{Q}$ is a real number? According to some articles, it's possible. But any explanation on this concept of treating positive definite matrices as positive numbers and why is this justified, which, I assume is part of a more generalised KKT condition?

P. S. The problem is part of my research problem and the exact function isn't important here. All I need is an explanation of using KKT condition on $\mathbf{Q}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look for [SDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming) (semidefinite programming).

Your problem is
\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize} \quad &f(Q)\\
\text{such that} \quad & Q \succeq 0 \\
\text{and} \quad &\mathrm{trace}(Q \, A ) \le P\end{align*}
You can associate the Lagrangian
$$
L(Q, R, \lambda) = f(Q) + \mathrm{trace}(Q \, R) + \lambda \, \mathrm{trace}(Q \, A ),
$$
for $R \preceq 0$ and $\lambda \ge 0$.
If a constraint qualification (CQ) is satisfied, the first order optimality conditions are
\begin{align*}L_Q = f'(Q) + R + \lambda \, A &= 0\\
\mathrm{trace}(Q \, R) &= 0\\
\lambda \, \mathrm{trace}(Q \, A ) &= 0
\end{align*}
That is, the positive-semidefinite constraint gets a negative-semidefinite multiplier $R$, satisfying the complementary slackness condition $\mathrm{trace}(Q \, R) = 0$.
This is similar to the $\le$ constraint, which gets a positive multiplier.

Comment: thanks a lot. But shouldn't the Lagrangian be$L\left(\mathbf{Q}, \mathbf{R}, \lambda\right)=f\left(\mathbf{Q}\right)+\text{Trace}\left(\mathbf{QR}\right)+ \lambda\left(\text{Trace}\left(\mathbf{QA}\right)-P\right)$

Comment: Yes, of course. I have forgotten the $-P$.